# Why doesn't repaint() work when called by a method of an object of the same class?

Tags: java, swing, paint

In a program I'm building for my class I have the same class extending a Swing JPanel and implementing MouseListener, for which I use two instantiations - one to function as a JPanel, and the other as a mouse listener for that JPanel.

But when I click in the window, repaint() the MouseClicked method in the mouse listener fails to call the first object's paintComponent() method. For example:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    static boolean black;
    static TestPanel test = new TestPanel();

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){ //Expected behavior: the square turns black immediately
        System.out.println("CLICK!");
        black = true;
        test.repaint(); //this fails
        try{
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         super.paintComponent(g);
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
         System.out.println("Painting...");
         g2d.setColor(Color.white);
         if(black){
             g2d.setColor(Color.black);
         }
         g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.addMouseListener(new TestPanel());
        test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        frame.add(test);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        while (true){
            black = false;
            test.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

If you watch what happens on a click, the screen stays white for the 3 seconds after the click is registered, until the loop starts up again, i.e., the repaint() call in the mouse listener didn't work. Why does this happen?

I'm guessing it would work if I made different classes for the objects, but I'm mostly curious as to *why* it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. If you want to delay an effect, schedule it on a single shot Swing based `Timer`.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without multiple threads? So far my program is only using one thread.

Comment: *"Is there any way to do that without multiple threads?"* The Swing `Timer` runs on the EDT..

Comment: It's weird, when I do the exact same thing in the main method it works fine. It's only in an external method that I encounter this problem.

Comment: Using a Timer isn't really what I had in mind since it's supposed to trigger on a mouse click, not a set duration between each update.

Comment: Nothing weird about it -- code run from the main method is not being run on the Swing event thread. But this is not a safe solution to your problem, since this introduces risks of other intermittent problems since you're running some Swing code off of the Swing event thread. As for `"...isn't really what I had in mind..."` -- hard to guess what you have in mind. What is the main purpose of your introducing a delay? If you need a set delay, then use a Swing Timer. If not, then what are you trying to do?

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood the function of a timer. Why do the main method and other methods run in different threads? If I made a new method that didn't call any Swing methods, would it still run in the event dispatch thread?

Comment: @MoldYeller: it depends where and how you call it. When you create a Swing GUI, the underlying Swing library creates several threads, the most important to know about is the EDT or event dispatch thread. To learn more about it, please see: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help! I wish I could upvote you as a new user.

Answer (score 0):

> for which I use two instantiations - one to function as a JPanel, and the other as a mouse listener for that JPanel.

There is no need to do that. All you need is a single instance of the `TestPanel` class.

In the constructor of your `TestPanel` class you just add:

```
addMouseListener( this);
```

The get rid of the static variable for the TestPanel class.

Then the code in your main method should look something like:

```
    //test.addMouseListener(new TestPanel());
    //test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    //frame.add(test);
    frame.add( new TestPanel() );
```

Also, the `TestPanel` class should override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the Dimension of your panel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for a working example with a `MouseListener`.

Comment: I checked your answer and, at least in the latest version of java, it gives compiler errors...

Comment: You're right in that it simplifies it, but the basic problem of repaint() not working inside MouseClicked() is still the same. It seems no matter what I try, I can't get repaint() to actually work inside that function.

Comment: @MoldYeller, yes it works!!! Read the tutorial and download the working example and test it yourself. Then start with the working code in the example and make your modifications. You were also told in the first comment to your question to get rid of the Thread.sleep(). I have no idea if you implemented the suggestions I made correctly since you haven't updated your code.

Answer (score 0):

The AWT thread is responsible for calling MouseListener and for repaint.
Inside the repaint(); method, the AWT thread is told to call the paint();
Just call it using a different thread. In general, it is a bad idea to do anything intensive with the AWT thread. It already does a lot, taking too much of its time will mess your GUI up.

Depending on your needs, this might work:

```
new Thread(()->{repaint();}).start();
```